# How let spring security response unauthorized(http 401 code) if requesting uri without authentication

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-boot

I'm using Spring Boot (1.2.6) and Spring Security (4.0.2).

The security configuration looks as follows:

```
@Configuration
@ConditionalOnWebApplication
@Profile("!integTest")
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true, prePostEnabled = true)
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableRedisHttpSession(maxInactiveIntervalInSeconds = 60 * 60 * 24 * 30)
class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    public static final String[] PROTECTED_RESOURCES = new String[] {  "/user/abc" };

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * 
     * @see org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.
     * WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter#configure(org.springframework.security.
     * config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity)
     */
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {    
        http
          .csrf().disable()
          .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(PROTECTED_RESOURCES)
            .hasRole("USER")
            .anyRequest()
            .permitAll()
          .and()
            .anonymous().disable();
    }

}
```

However, the Spring Security Framework responds with a 403 (Access is denied) when the anonymous user is accessing the protected resource (**/user/abc**).

I'm wondering how to configure Spring to respond with a HTTP 401 code when an anonymous user is accessing the protected URL.

Below is the log after setting `DEBUG` level on `ExceptionTranslationFilter`.

```
2015-11-20 10:59:07.406 DEBUG 14542 --- [nio-8000-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2015-11-20 10:59:07.410  INFO 14542 --- [nio-8000-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2015-11-20 10:59:07.411  INFO 14542 --- [nio-8000-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization started
2015-11-20 10:59:07.412 DEBUG 14542 --- [nio-8000-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Using MultipartResolver [org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardServletMultipartResolver@29e7e0b6]
2015-11-20 10:59:07.424 DEBUG 14542 --- [nio-8000-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Unable to locate LocaleResolver with name 'localeResolver': using default [org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.AcceptHeaderLocaleResolver@bf0f97a]
2015-11-20 10:59:07.434 DEBUG 14542 --- [nio-8000-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Unable to locate ThemeResolver with name 'themeResolver': using default [org.springframework.web.servlet.theme.FixedThemeResolver@1189d7ae]
2015-11-20 10:59:07.453 DEBUG 14542 --- [nio-8000-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Unable to locate RequestToViewNameTranslator with name 'viewNameTranslator': using default [org.springframework.web.servlet.view.DefaultRequestToViewNameTranslator@859e51c]
2015-11-20 10:59:07.466 DEBUG 14542 --- [nio-8000-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Unable to locate FlashMapManager with name 'flashMapManager': using default [org.springframework.web.servlet.support.SessionFlashMapManager@18f8476f]
2015-11-20 10:59:07.466 DEBUG 14542 --- [nio-8000-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Published WebApplicationContext of servlet 'dispatcherServlet' as ServletContext attribute with name [org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.CONTEXT.dispatcherServlet]
2015-11-20 10:59:07.466  INFO 14542 --- [nio-8000-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization completed in 55 ms
2015-11-20 10:59:07.466 DEBUG 14542 --- [nio-8000-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Servlet 'dispatcherServlet' configured successfully
2015-11-20 10:59:07.496 DEBUG 14542 --- [nio-8000-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /user/momentStats at position 1 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter'
2015-11-20 10:59:07.497 DEBUG 14542 --- [nio-8000-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /user/momentStats at position 2 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
2015-11-20 10:59:07.498 DEBUG 14542 --- [nio-8000-exec-1] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : No HttpSession currently exists
2015-11-20 10:59:07.498 DEBUG 14542 --- [nio-8000-exec-1] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : No SecurityContext was available from the HttpSession: null. A new one will be created.
2015-11-20 10:59:07.518 DEBUG 14542 --- [nio-8000-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /user/momentStats at position 3 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'HeaderWriterFilter'
2015-11-20 10:59:07.519 DEBUG 14542 --- [nio-8000-exec-1] o.s.s.w.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter  : Not injecting HSTS header since it did not match the requestMatcher org.springframework.security.web.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter$SecureRequestMatcher@96c224
2015-11-20 10:59:07.519 DEBUG 14542 --- [nio-8000-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /user/momentStats at position 4 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'LogoutFilter'
2015-11-20 10:59:07.519 DEBUG 14542 --- [nio-8000-exec-1] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/user/momentstats'; against '/logout'
2015-11-20 10:59:07.520 DEBUG 14542 --- [nio-8000-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /user/momentStats at position 5 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'RequestCacheAwareFilter'
2015-11-20 10:59:07.522 DEBUG 14542 --- [nio-8000-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /user/momentStats at position 6 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter'
2015-11-20 10:59:07.524 DEBUG 14542 --- [nio-8000-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /user/momentStats at position 7 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'AnonymousAuthenticationFilter'
2015-11-20 10:59:07.532 DEBUG 14542 --- [nio-8000-exec-1] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Populated SecurityContextHolder with anonymous token: 'org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@9055e4a6: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@957e: RemoteIpAddress: 127.0.0.1; SessionId: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS'
2015-11-20 10:59:07.532 DEBUG 14542 --- [nio-8000-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /user/momentStats at position 8 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SessionManagementFilter'
2015-11-20 10:59:07.532 DEBUG 14542 --- [nio-8000-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /user/momentStats at position 9 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'ExceptionTranslationFilter'
2015-11-20 10:59:07.532 DEBUG 14542 --- [nio-8000-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /user/momentStats at position 10 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'FilterSecurityInterceptor'
2015-11-20 10:59:07.533 DEBUG 14542 --- [nio-8000-exec-1] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/user/momentstats'; against '/art/**/making'
2015-11-20 10:59:07.533 DEBUG 14542 --- [nio-8000-exec-1] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/user/momentstats'; against '/orders/**/payment/wx'
2015-11-20 10:59:07.533 DEBUG 14542 --- [nio-8000-exec-1] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/user/momentstats'; against '/user/momentstats'
2015-11-20 10:59:07.534 DEBUG 14542 --- [nio-8000-exec-1] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Secure object: FilterInvocation: URL: /user/momentStats; Attributes: [authenticated]
2015-11-20 10:59:07.534 DEBUG 14542 --- [nio-8000-exec-1] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Previously Authenticated: org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@9055e4a6: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@957e: RemoteIpAddress: 127.0.0.1; SessionId: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS
2015-11-20 10:59:07.551 DEBUG 14542 --- [nio-8000-exec-1] o.s.s.access.vote.AffirmativeBased       : Voter: org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter@4d0267b0, returned: -1
2015-11-20 10:59:07.563 DEBUG 14542 --- [nio-8000-exec-1] o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter     : Access is denied (user is anonymous); redirecting to authentication entry point

org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access is denied
    at org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased.decide(AffirmativeBased.java:83)
    at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.beforeInvocation(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:232)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:123)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:90)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:122)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:169)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:48)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:120)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:64)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:91)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:53)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:213)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:176)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at io.vme.wechat.filter.SimpleCORSFilter.doFilterInternal(SimpleCORSFilter.java:49)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.session.web.http.SessionRepositoryFilter.doFilterInternal(SessionRepositoryFilter.java:125)
    at org.springframework.session.web.http.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:65)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:673)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1526)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1482)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

2015-11-20 10:59:07.565 DEBUG 14542 --- [nio-8000-exec-1] o.s.s.w.util.matcher.AndRequestMatcher   : Trying to match using NegatedRequestMatcher [requestMatcher=Ant [pattern='/**/favicon.ico']]
2015-11-20 10:59:07.565 DEBUG 14542 --- [nio-8000-exec-1] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/user/momentstats'; against '/**/favicon.ico'
2015-11-20 10:59:07.565 DEBUG 14542 --- [nio-8000-exec-1] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.NegatedRequestMatcher  : matches = true
2015-11-20 10:59:07.566 DEBUG 14542 --- [nio-8000-exec-1] o.s.s.w.util.matcher.AndRequestMatcher   : Trying to match using NegatedRequestMatcher [requestMatcher=MediaTypeRequestMatcher [contentNegotiationStrategy=org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationManager@6036ed6e, matchingMediaTypes=[application/json], useEquals=false, ignoredMediaTypes=[*/*]]]
2015-11-20 10:59:07.584 DEBUG 14542 --- [nio-8000-exec-1] o.s.s.w.u.m.MediaTypeRequestMatcher      : httpRequestMediaTypes=[text/html, application/xhtml+xml, image/webp, application/xml;q=0.9, */*;q=0.8]
2015-11-20 10:59:07.584 DEBUG 14542 --- [nio-8000-exec-1] o.s.s.w.u.m.MediaTypeRequestMatcher      : Processing text/html
2015-11-20 10:59:07.584 DEBUG 14542 --- [nio-8000-exec-1] o.s.s.w.u.m.MediaTypeRequestMatcher      : application/json .isCompatibleWith text/html = false
2015-11-20 10:59:07.584 DEBUG 14542 --- [nio-8000-exec-1] o.s.s.w.u.m.MediaTypeRequestMatcher      : Processing application/xhtml+xml
2015-11-20 10:59:07.584 DEBUG 14542 --- [nio-8000-exec-1] o.s.s.w.u.m.MediaTypeRequestMatcher      : application/json .isCompatibleWith application/xhtml+xml = false
2015-11-20 10:59:07.584 DEBUG 14542 --- [nio-8000-exec-1] o.s.s.w.u.m.MediaTypeRequestMatcher      : Processing image/webp
2015-11-20 10:59:07.584 DEBUG 14542 --- [nio-8000-exec-1] o.s.s.w.u.m.MediaTypeRequestMatcher      : application/json .isCompatibleWith image/webp = false
2015-11-20 10:59:07.584 DEBUG 14542 --- [nio-8000-exec-1] o.s.s.w.u.m.MediaTypeRequestMatcher      : Processing application/xml;q=0.9
2015-11-20 10:59:07.584 DEBUG 14542 --- [nio-8000-exec-1] o.s.s.w.u.m.MediaTypeRequestMatcher      : application/json .isCompatibleWith application/xml;q=0.9 = false
2015-11-20 10:59:07.584 DEBUG 14542 --- [nio-8000-exec-1] o.s.s.w.u.m.MediaTypeRequestMatcher      : Processing */*;q=0.8
2015-11-20 10:59:07.584 DEBUG 14542 --- [nio-8000-exec-1] o.s.s.w.u.m.MediaTypeRequestMatcher      : Ignoring
2015-11-20 10:59:07.584 DEBUG 14542 --- [nio-8000-exec-1] o.s.s.w.u.m.MediaTypeRequestMatcher      : Did not match any media types
2015-11-20 10:59:07.584 DEBUG 14542 --- [nio-8000-exec-1] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.NegatedRequestMatcher  : matches = true
2015-11-20 10:59:07.584 DEBUG 14542 --- [nio-8000-exec-1] o.s.s.w.util.matcher.AndRequestMatcher   : Trying to match using NegatedRequestMatcher [requestMatcher=RequestHeaderRequestMatcher [expectedHeaderName=X-Requested-With, expectedHeaderValue=XMLHttpRequest]]
2015-11-20 10:59:07.585 DEBUG 14542 --- [nio-8000-exec-1] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.NegatedRequestMatcher  : matches = true
2015-11-20 10:59:07.585 DEBUG 14542 --- [nio-8000-exec-1] o.s.s.w.util.matcher.AndRequestMatcher   : All requestMatchers returned true
2015-11-20 10:59:07.593 DEBUG 14542 --- [nio-8000-exec-1] o.s.s.w.s.HttpSessionRequestCache        : DefaultSavedRequest added to Session: DefaultSavedRequest[http://127.0.0.1:8000/user/momentStats]
2015-11-20 10:59:07.594 DEBUG 14542 --- [nio-8000-exec-1] o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter     : Calling Authentication entry point.
2015-11-20 10:59:07.595 DEBUG 14542 --- [nio-8000-exec-1] o.s.s.w.a.Http403ForbiddenEntryPoint     : Pre-authenticated entry point called. Rejecting access
2015-11-20 10:59:07.595 DEBUG 14542 --- [nio-8000-exec-1] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : SecurityContext is empty or contents are anonymous - context will not be stored in HttpSession.
2015-11-20 10:59:07.772 DEBUG 14542 --- [nio-8000-exec-1] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
2015-11-20 10:59:07.784 DEBUG 14542 --- [nio-8000-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet' processing GET request for [/error]
2015-11-20 10:59:07.787 DEBUG 14542 --- [nio-8000-exec-1] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Looking up handler method for path /error
2015-11-20 10:59:07.791 DEBUG 14542 --- [nio-8000-exec-1] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Returning handler method [public io.vme.wechat.model.dto.ErrorDTO io.vme.wechat.controller.VMEErrorHandler.handleError(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)]
2015-11-20 10:59:07.794 DEBUG 14542 --- [nio-8000-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Last-Modified value for [/error] is: -1
2015-11-20 10:59:08.011 DEBUG 14542 --- [nio-8000-exec-1] m.m.a.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor : Written [org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonValue@663d36b1] as "application/json" using [org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter@68a39825]
2015-11-20 10:59:08.011 DEBUG 14542 --- [nio-8000-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Null ModelAndView returned to DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet': assuming HandlerAdapter completed request handling
2015-11-20 10:59:08.011 DEBUG 14542 --- [nio-8000-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Successfully completed request
2015-11-20 10:59:08.480 DEBUG 14542 --- [nio-8000-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /favicon.ico at position 1 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter'
2015-11-20 10:59:08.481 DEBUG 14542 --- [nio-8000-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /favicon.ico at position 2 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
2015-11-20 10:59:08.493 DEBUG 14542 --- [nio-8000-exec-2] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : HttpSession returned null object for SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT
2015-11-20 10:59:08.494 DEBUG 14542 --- [nio-8000-exec-2] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : No SecurityContext was available from the HttpSession: org.springframework.session.web.http.SessionRepositoryFilter$SessionRepositoryRequestWrapper$HttpSessionWrapper@5fc0b4a0. A new one will be created.
2015-11-20 10:59:08.494 DEBUG 14542 --- [nio-8000-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /favicon.ico at position 3 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'HeaderWriterFilter'
2015-11-20 10:59:08.494 DEBUG 14542 --- [nio-8000-exec-2] o.s.s.w.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter  : Not injecting HSTS header since it did not match the requestMatcher org.springframework.security.web.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter$SecureRequestMatcher@96c224
2015-11-20 10:59:08.494 DEBUG 14542 --- [nio-8000-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /favicon.ico at position 4 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'LogoutFilter'
2015-11-20 10:59:08.494 DEBUG 14542 --- [nio-8000-exec-2] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/favicon.ico'; against '/logout'
2015-11-20 10:59:08.494 DEBUG 14542 --- [nio-8000-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /favicon.ico at position 5 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'RequestCacheAwareFilter'
2015-11-20 10:59:08.494 DEBUG 14542 --- [nio-8000-exec-2] o.s.s.w.s.DefaultSavedRequest            : pathInfo: both null (property equals)
2015-11-20 10:59:08.494 DEBUG 14542 --- [nio-8000-exec-2] o.s.s.w.s.DefaultSavedRequest            : queryString: both null (property equals)
2015-11-20 10:59:08.495 DEBUG 14542 --- [nio-8000-exec-2] o.s.s.w.s.DefaultSavedRequest            : requestURI: arg1=/user/momentStats; arg2=/favicon.ico (property not equals)
2015-11-20 10:59:08.495 DEBUG 14542 --- [nio-8000-exec-2] o.s.s.w.s.HttpSessionRequestCache        : saved request doesn't match
2015-11-20 10:59:08.495 DEBUG 14542 --- [nio-8000-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /favicon.ico at position 6 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter'
2015-11-20 10:59:08.495 DEBUG 14542 --- [nio-8000-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /favicon.ico at position 7 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'AnonymousAuthenticationFilter'
2015-11-20 10:59:08.495 DEBUG 14542 --- [nio-8000-exec-2] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Populated SecurityContextHolder with anonymous token: 'org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@6faba4dc: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@fffed504: RemoteIpAddress: 127.0.0.1; SessionId: e3e46247-a88a-4c60-8574-6579f00d5e9d; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS'
2015-11-20 10:59:08.495 DEBUG 14542 --- [nio-8000-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /favicon.ico at position 8 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SessionManagementFilter'
2015-11-20 10:59:08.495 DEBUG 14542 --- [nio-8000-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /favicon.ico at position 9 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'ExceptionTranslationFilter'
2015-11-20 10:59:08.495 DEBUG 14542 --- [nio-8000-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /favicon.ico at position 10 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'FilterSecurityInterceptor'
2015-11-20 10:59:08.495 DEBUG 14542 --- [nio-8000-exec-2] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/favicon.ico'; against '/art/**/making'
2015-11-20 10:59:08.495 DEBUG 14542 --- [nio-8000-exec-2] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/favicon.ico'; against '/orders/**/payment/wx'
2015-11-20 10:59:08.495 DEBUG 14542 --- [nio-8000-exec-2] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/favicon.ico'; against '/user/momentstats'
2015-11-20 10:59:08.495 DEBUG 14542 --- [nio-8000-exec-2] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Secure object: FilterInvocation: URL: /favicon.ico; Attributes: [permitAll]
2015-11-20 10:59:08.495 DEBUG 14542 --- [nio-8000-exec-2] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Previously Authenticated: org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@6faba4dc: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@fffed504: RemoteIpAddress: 127.0.0.1; SessionId: e3e46247-a88a-4c60-8574-6579f00d5e9d; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS
2015-11-20 10:59:08.497 DEBUG 14542 --- [nio-8000-exec-2] o.s.s.access.vote.AffirmativeBased       : Voter: org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter@4d0267b0, returned: 1
2015-11-20 10:59:08.497 DEBUG 14542 --- [nio-8000-exec-2] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Authorization successful
2015-11-20 10:59:08.497 DEBUG 14542 --- [nio-8000-exec-2] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : RunAsManager did not change Authentication object
2015-11-20 10:59:08.497 DEBUG 14542 --- [nio-8000-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /favicon.ico reached end of additional filter chain; proceeding with original chain
2015-11-20 10:59:08.497 DEBUG 14542 --- [nio-8000-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet' processing GET request for [/favicon.ico]
2015-11-20 10:59:08.498 DEBUG 14542 --- [nio-8000-exec-2] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Matching patterns for request [/favicon.ico] are [/**/favicon.ico]
2015-11-20 10:59:08.499 DEBUG 14542 --- [nio-8000-exec-2] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : URI Template variables for request [/favicon.ico] are {}
2015-11-20 10:59:08.500 DEBUG 14542 --- [nio-8000-exec-2] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapping [/favicon.ico] to HandlerExecutionChain with handler [ResourceHttpRequestHandler [locations=[class path resource [META-INF/resources/], class path resource [resources/], class path resource [static/], class path resource [public/], class path resource []], resolvers=[org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.PathResourceResolver@320e179f]]] and 1 interceptor
2015-11-20 10:59:08.501 DEBUG 14542 --- [nio-8000-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Last-Modified value for [/favicon.ico] is: -1
2015-11-20 10:59:08.531 DEBUG 14542 --- [nio-8000-exec-2] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : SecurityContext is empty or contents are anonymous - context will not be stored in HttpSession.
2015-11-20 10:59:08.538 DEBUG 14542 --- [nio-8000-exec-2] tRepository$SaveToSessionResponseWrapper : Skip invoking on
2015-11-20 10:59:08.539 DEBUG 14542 --- [nio-8000-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Null ModelAndView returned to DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet': assuming HandlerAdapter completed request handling
2015-11-20 10:59:08.540 DEBUG 14542 --- [nio-8000-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Successfully completed request
2015-11-20 10:59:08.541 DEBUG 14542 --- [nio-8000-exec-2] o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter     : Chain processed normally
2015-11-20 10:59:08.542 DEBUG 14542 --- [nio-8000-exec-2] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Update your Spring Boot version to 1.3.0.RELEASE and you'll get [`Http401AuthenticationEntryPoint`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v1.3.0.RELEASE/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/security/Http401AuthenticationEntryPoint.java) for free. Configure authentication entry point in your security configuration like this:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {   
    http
      .csrf().disable()
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers(PROTECTED_RESOURCES)
        .hasRole("USER")
        .anyRequest()
        .permitAll()
      .and()
        .anonymous().disable()
        .exceptionHandling()
        .authenticationEntryPoint(new org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.Http401AuthenticationEntryPoint("headerValue"));
}
```

and Spring Boot will return `HTTP 401`:

```
Status Code: 401 Unauthorized
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Expires: 0
Pragma: no-cache
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
WWW-Authenticate: headerValue
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block
```

Comment: why disable anonymous context here?

Answer (score 51):

In Spring Boot 2, there is no more `Http401AuthenticationEntryPoint`, instead you can use [HttpStatusEntryPoint](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.0.4.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/HttpStatusEntryPoint.html) which return a response with the corresponding HTTP status.

```
http
  .exceptionHandling()
  .authenticationEntryPoint(new HttpStatusEntryPoint(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED))
```

Answer (score 21):

You need to extend AuthenticationEntryPoint to do customization based upon the exceptions or reason of Auth Failure.

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class MyAuthenticationEntryPoint implements AuthenticationEntryPoint {
  @Override
  public void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException authException)
      throws IOException, ServletException {
    // 401
    response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, "Authentication Failed");
  }

  @ExceptionHandler (value = {AccessDeniedException.class})
  public void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
      AccessDeniedException accessDeniedException) throws IOException {
    // 403
    response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_FORBIDDEN, "Authorization Failed : " + accessDeniedException.getMessage());
  }

  @ExceptionHandler (value = {Exception.class})
  public void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
      Exception exception) throws IOException {
     // 500
    response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, "Internal Server Error : " + exception.getMessage());
  }

}
```

Specify the above custom AuthenticationEntryPoint in your SecurityConfig like below:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity (prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.exceptionHandling()
        .authenticationEntryPoint(new MyAuthenticationEntryPoint());
  }

}
```

Answer (score 4):

You configured no authentication (Form Login, HTTP Basic, ...) so the default `AuthenticationEntryPoint`is used, see [Spring Security API](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configurers/ExceptionHandlingConfigurer.html#authenticationEntryPoint-org.springframework.security.web.AuthenticationEntryPoint-):

> Sets the `AuthenticationEntryPoint` to be used.
>
> If no `authenticationEntryPoint(AuthenticationEntryPoint)` is specified, then `defaultAuthenticationEntryPointFor(AuthenticationEntryPoint, RequestMatcher)` will be used. The first `AuthenticationEntryPoint` will be used as the default is no matches were found.
>
> If that is not provided defaults to `Http403ForbiddenEntryPoint`.

You can set the `AuthenticationEntryPoint` as @ksokol wrote or configure a authentication, which defines a `AuthenticationEntryPoint`.

Answer (score 2):

In 2021, for spring security version 5.x.x.
If you are not using BasicAuthenticationFilter or AbstractAuthenticationFilter and are using your own custom filter for authentication without providing any AuthenticationEntryPoint and you are thinking like I did that unauthenticated user will be automatically be handled by spring security through ExeptionTranslatorFilter, then you are going to be frustrated like me.
@dur answer helped me, but the link was not working
so here is the updated link of official documentation of current version mentioning this clearly
[authenticationEntryPont](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configurers/ExceptionHandlingConfigurer.html#authenticationEntryPoint-org.springframework.security.web.AuthenticationEntryPoint-)

> If no `authenticationEntryPoint(AuthenticationEntryPoint)` is specified,
> then `defaultAuthenticationEntryPointFor(AuthenticationEntryPoint, RequestMatcher)` will be used.
>
> The first `AuthenticationEntryPoint` will be used as the default if no matches were found.
>
> If that is not provided defaults to `Http403ForbiddenEntryPoint`.

So basically you have to create you own authentication entry point like mentioned in other answers after which things should work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

For the situation here, as it tried to access a protected resource ("/user/abc"), this is handled by ExceptionTranslationFilter and its configured authenticationEntryPoint (like OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint), also you may need to check the exceptionTranslator of the authenticationEntryPoint (default to DefaultWebResponseExceptionTranslator).

Just in case, if someone expects to have 401 from `/oauth/token` when user credential is invalid (https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/issues/1906), you may need to check the `exceptionTranslator` of `AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer`.