# Change response status onUnsuccessfulAuthentication

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

The whole purpose of this is to have a different error message on the frontend when the user is blocked, a different message when the username is not found and when the password is incorrect.

```
public class CustomAuthenticationFilter extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter {

    @Override
    public void unsuccessfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
                                           AuthenticationException exception) throws IOException, ServletException {
        if (exception.getMessage().contains("404")) {
            response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_NOT_FOUND);
        } else if (exception.getMessage().contains("disabled")) {
            response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_CONFLICT);
            response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_CONFLICT);
            response.setHeader("test", "test");
        }
        super.unsuccessfulAuthentication(request, response, exception);
    }
}
```

I am trying to change the response error status based on the message of the exception.

This class extends the `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter` and overrides the `unsuccessfulAuthentication` method. The `unsuccessfulAuthentication` method is called each time the authentication is unsuccessful.

**Even though the response status is set to e.g. conflict, the browser receives 403 unauthorized error.**

I don't seem to be able to modify the response status and message/output in any way.

What kind of solution would you recommend to solve this issue?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How let spring security response unauthorized(http 401 code) if requesting uri without authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33801468/how-let-spring-security-response-unauthorizedhttp-401-code-if-requesting-uri-w)

Comment: From a security standpoint never let the user know if his password is incorrect or his username is not found.

Comment: @Karim right, right, I know about this, but we want to let the user know

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, I needed to put the "return" keyword before the end of the method.